# Truncating the high degree part of a positive boolean function doesn't change the distance to positive functions too much

Tags: co.combinatorics, fourier-analysis, computer-science, boolean-algebras

Given $\displaystyle n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, suppose $\displaystyle f:\{-1,1\}^n\to[0,1], $ then $f$ has a Fourier expansion:

$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{S\subseteq[n]} \tilde{f}(S)x^S,$ where $\displaystyle x^S=\prod_{i\in S}x_i$ and $\tilde{f}(S)\in\mathbb{R}$.

For further details, please see ['ANALYSIS OF BOOLEAN FUNCTIONS'](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.10386.pdf)  by Ryan O’Donnell in chapter 1).

If  $f(x)<0$, we define $\displaystyle f^{\leq d}=\sum_{|S|\leq d}\tilde{f}(S)x^S$, $\displaystyle \zeta(f,x)=(f(x))^2 $ and $\zeta(f,x)=0$  elsewhere.

My question is whether the following is true
$$\exists c_1,c_2>0 \; \forall n,\epsilon>0\; \forall f:\{-1,1\}^n\to[0,1] \; \forall d>c_1(\log(1/\epsilon))^{c_2},\; 2^{-n}\sum_{x\in\{-1,1\}^n} \zeta(f^{\leq d},x)\leq \epsilon$$

Here, it is required that $A(d)$ depends only on $d$ and is independent of $n$ i.e. after truncating the high-degree part, the average distance to positive functions is still bounded.

From Proposition 3.2 in ['ANALYSIS OF BOOLEAN FUNCTIONS'](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.10386.pdf) we can get a bound $O(n)$. Some simple functions like $\displaystyle \prod_i(\frac{1±x_i}{2})$ is believed to satisfy the above. Is there any counterexample?

Comment: Isn’t the bound just 1? Just bound it by the expectation of $(f^{\leq d})^2$ (without restricting to negative arguments), then use Parseval twice?

Comment: @JasonGaitonde You are right, I have changed the question